# How to set secrets for a bunch of users that will have multiple fields?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: john-secret
data:
  USERNAME: abc=
  PASSWORD: def=

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: jane-secret
data:
  USERNAME: ghi=
  PASSWORD: jkl=
```

Then I could include them like:

```
env:
  - name: JOHN_USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: john-secret
        key: USERNAME
  - name: JOHN_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: john-secret
        key: PASSWORD
  - name: JANE_USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: jane-secret
        key: USERNAME
  - name: JANE_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: jane-secret
        key: PASSWORD
```

And use them in Node.js app like `process.env.JOHN_USERNAME`, etc..

This works, but is there a cleaner/easier way to set secrets for a bunch of users that will have multiple fields? I imagine this would get messy with say 100 users x 5 fields.

Comment: What is the purpose of these accounts? Is there a login area for the app?

Comment: @mbuechmann It is just an example to learn how to do the secret functionality. :)

Comment: @kayla it's best to learn on practical scenarios that make sense. If you try to learn on something that is nonsense, you will have hard time applying it to real life problem. This is not to say you should not experiment and should try do unusual things, but it usually more practical to learn the basics first and then go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [mount the secret as a volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-pod-that-has-access-to-the-secret-data-through-a-volume).  Adapting the example from the linked Kubernetes documentation:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
          - name: john-secret
            mountPath: /etc/john-secret
  volumes:
    - name: secret-volume
      secret:
        secretName: john-secret
```

If you have a bunch of secrets, you'd need to mount them all into the pod spec.  That's a maintainability problem in itself.

I don't think anything actually stops you from using a more structured data object, like a JSON or YAML file, as the value of a secret.  That could work reasonably in combination with mounting it as a volume.

If you truly have a lot of secrets – many "users" with many values for each – then some sort of external storage for the secrets is probably a better idea.  If they're just usernames and passwords, it's very common to store a one-way hash of the password in a database (which also allows them to be updated without redeploying the system).  Tools like Hashicorp's [Vault](https://vaultproject.io/) can be complicated to administer, but have actual security of this content as a priority, and you get much more rigorous control over who can access the actual secrets.

Comment: Already plan to switch to Vault in the future. Thank you. :) Didn’t know you could do JSON as secret value. That’s what I need!

Comment: Can you show an example of storing JSON/an object as the secret value? Would I have to stringify it -> base64 encode it? Then when using it, I would have to re-parse the JSON string?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  From the point of view of your process you'd see an `/etc/secret-mount-path/secret-key.json` file.